# Java - Read information about another program?

Tags: java, pixel, ram

So I want to make a Java program that can read data from another program. It's from a game, and I can't (to my knowledge) get the information from the files (it's run serverside). How would I do this? Currently I'm reading pixels from the screen, but I don't think it's the proper way to do it. Can I somehow access the RAM? The information would be stored there. Problem with reading the pixels is it should run on more computers, and they don't necessarily have the same resolution / placement of the window (could be windowed mode). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using a different language such as C++? You can develop a dynamic link library which you can inject into the game and read from memory using pointers. Otherwise you can use JNA and use `ReadProcessMemory` to read memory from the process

Comment: Only problem is I don't know any of the C languages.

Comment: i've just expanded on my comment and left an answer for you, hope it helps you mate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java isn't necessarily the best language for this. A way of accomplishing what you want to do is make an injectable DLL which uses pointers to read from the memory or use `ReadProcessMemory` to read memory from an external process.

If you're sure you want to use Java for this you can use the [JNA Library](https://github.com/twall/jna) to access the native method `ReadProcessMemory` and you can find the memory addresses using a tool like [CheatEngine](http://www.cheatengine.org/).

To load in `Kernel32` (where the `ReadProcessMemory` method is) you must do something along the lines of this:

```
Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);
```

You then need to know the access rights you need to accomplish what you want to do, which can be found at [Microsoft's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In this case we're wanting to read only so the access right we need is `PROCESS_VM_READ (0x0010)`. We can then store this value in a const:

```
public static final int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;
```

Then if we look up the syntax of [ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), we find that the syntax is like this:

```
BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory(
  _In_   HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_   LPCVOID lpBaseAddress,
  _Out_  LPVOID lpBuffer,
  _In_   SIZE_T nSize,
  _Out_  SIZE_T *lpNumberOfBytesRead
);
```

`ReadProcessMemory` takes a process handle (`Pointer` in JNA), the memory address to read from (lets say we want to read from static value `0x10101AAA82`), the buffer to read to, the size of the value and the last value which outputs the number of bytes read we'll set to `null` since we don't really care.

So first, we want to open a pointer to the process we want to read from, assuming you know the PID of the process:

```
Pointer process = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, pid);
```

and now we have the handle to the process (ie. the first parameter of `ReadProcessMemory`

The buffer we're going to read to is going to be an instance of [Memory](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Memory.html) which we can instantiate by passing in the size of the value we want to read, lets say I want to read 2 bytes in this situation.

```
Memory memory = new Memory(2);
```

We've now got all the parameters we need to read our memory value:

```
kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(process, 0x10101AAA82, memory, 2, null);
```

Which means we want to read `2 bytes` from memory address `0x10101AAA82` from process `process` into the `memory` memory.

Now we can get the value of what we've just read! If my value is an integer we can call `getInt(offset)` on `memory` and since we want to read from the start we'll pass in `0` as the offset. You can also run `getString`, `getChar` or anything listed on the [javadoc](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Memory.html). And now you have your value!

Comment: No problem, if you have any more questions feel free to ask

Comment: which language is better for this kind of stuff?

Comment: @Hamid a low level language like rust or c++

Answer (score 1):

You are actually trying to more or less program a bot.
I would recommend trying to figure out what are the files and/or ports responsible for this information passing (which can be hard).
And I am not sure that Java is the best way to go about it. (Visual Basic maybe?)

Comment: Ah interesting. Analyzing the packets coming in. It's not a bot (well, not for cheating), it's supposed to gather data about your game and analyze it, so the user can see the results.

Comment: That is how I would go about it. But it can be tricky. Consider that you will have to reverse engineer the communication interface, which is not code per say, but compiled, machine code.